# Angular Material Table- how to save data?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have the basic angular material table. Is there any possibility to save the data which is displayed in the table (I mean to save every row of data) when you click a button? If yes, how can I do it? How can I get every row of data? I want to save every row of data as an object and push it to an array.

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 showFirstLastButtons 
                 aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="saveData()">Warn</button>
```

Comment: Where are you planning to save it?

Comment: I want to save it in an array (because I need to send it to the backend). Somehow every row to be an object which will be pushed to the array. But I'm looking for any possibility

Comment: You can find the data inside of the `dataSource`. It should already be an array of objects (or possibly a `MatTableDataSource`, in which case you can find the data in `dataSource.data`).

Answer (score 1):

**codeSolution**:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wn7vwb-su3tun?file=app/table-basic-example.ts

this might help you

html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.symbol}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="saveData()">Warn</button>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  saveData() {
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }
}
```